# Read a CSV file from the Internet

Tags: java

I'm trying to read data (stock prices) from a CSV file on the Internet, but instead I received something like this:

```
(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.type = 'text/javascript';
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        URL url12 = new URL("http://www.cophieu68.com/export/excel.php?id=BBS");
        URLConnection urlConn = url12.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(inStream);
        String content1 = buff.readLine();
        String content2 = buff.readLine();
        while (content2 != null) {
            System.out.println(content2);
            content2 = buff.readLine();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("KHONG TAI DUOC DU LIEU");
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there appears to be a problem with the server. If you trace the connection, you will notice that the response is:

```
HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Wed, 01 Feb 2012 08:48:48 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.1.6
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-Description: File Transfer
Content-Disposition: csv; filename=excel_bbs.csv; size=46925
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=2lgqidrmqrvu3piu47ulvrn5t3; path=/
Set-Cookie: cophieu68_LanuageView=vn; expires=Fri, 02-Mar-2012 08:48:48 GMT
Location: http://www.cophieu68.com/wap
...
```

If you follow the redirection link (http://www.cophieu68.com/wap) you will  get what your client is receiving. I have no idea why the server is set up this way, but if you disable redirects in your clients you will receive your CSV. You can do this by adding the following lines:

```
URLConnection urlConn = url12.openConnection();
// Disable redirects
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)urlConn;
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream());
```

If you have control of the server check if you really need to send this response.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read a `.csv`file, but the link you are using is actually a webpage that will redirect you to the CSV.

Check for redirects or use another link (:

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you retreive some Javascript and not the data you want. Check your URL.

Comment: When I access the link from browser, it give me the csv file normally :(

Comment: The enable HTTP monitoring in your browser or use some tool like `curl` to check the details of the HTTP request(s) made.